# With structure Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

It run into error if i run the following code

```
With pt
    .Field.ClearAllFilters
    .Field.CurrentPage = CustomerName
    .RefreshTable
End With
```

but i can run this code

```
With pt
    Field.ClearAllFilters
    Field.CurrentPage = CustomerName
    pt.RefreshTable
End With
```

the dots cause an error , can anyone explain?
Appreciate a lot for any reply
Thank

Comment: The [dots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement#remarks) do not cause [an error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The first code will not run because `PivotTable` (assuming `pt` is one) [does not have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable#methods) a property called `Field`. The second code will not run because there is no global object called `Field`.

Comment: Note that in the second one the `With pt` is not used at all. It is the same as you remove the `With pt` and `End With`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could benefit from reading up on how `With` is meant to work, in the documentation for the [With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) in VBA. Quoting:

> The With statement allows you to perform a series of statements on a
>   specified object without requalifying the name of the object. For
>   example, to change a number of different properties on a single
>   object, place the property assignment statements within the With
>   control structure, referring to the object once instead of referring
>   to it with each property assignment.

Note that `With` works on properties of a **single object**. It only works if the properties you use in the code actually exist for the object.

You can use the Object Browser to find out about an object's properties, or, again, take a look at the documentation [like this one for the pivot table object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable), which lists all methods and properties for an object.